# Why does my Chrome still trust Thawte certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, chrome, web

Thawte certificates are supposed to be invalid since Chrome 70, but I have Chrome 70.0.3538.102 and it accepts certificate of [this](https://cs.sportsdirect.com/) site just fine. Does anyone know, why that is? Should I be worried?

Comment: It does not accept this site for me: NET::ERR_CERT_SYMANTEC_LEGACY, Chrome 70 on Linux. Have you looked at the certificate chain? Maybe you have some local antivirus doing SSL interception which results in Chrome getting a certificate signed by a different CA?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Does not accept for my roommate either, but it does for me. Maybe its Win 8.1? It is weird. And yes, I have ESET but I see thawte in Chrome, that is how I spotted it.

Comment: Maybe you have manually added the CA to your Windows Truststore. This could also be done by some software installer. It is a good idea to clean out that list regularly. Unlike Firefox Chrome does not have its own store (I am however not sure how they revoke certs, if this applies  also to modified CA stores)

Comment: @eckes removing the CA manually prevents me from accessing the page, but it is different. That is standard invalid cert. It should show symantec legacy error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Weird phased rollout mechanism.

Their rollout mechanism was supposed to be "in v70 it STOPS working!". But now they seem to have settled on something like *"in v70 it will show a warning in the dev console and stop working for SOME (tm) users! And we will phase it in completely when we feel like it."*

#### Details here:

- https://twitter.com/hanno/status/1052556264994004993 , https://archive.fo/wFAGm
- https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/symantec-legacy-pki , https://archive.fo/TtE7Z

Comment: I suspected it may be the slow rollout Google does sometimes, but the blog said it will be distrusted by 70 immediately and that made more sense to me for a security update. Thanks for the information.